# I want to separate values in mysql using join in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My mysql table look like

```
ranks are rank1,rank2,rank3 on id 1
but i want to show like that 
id 1 -> rank1
id 1 -> rank2
id 1 -> rank 3
```

Comment: can you show mysql query?

Comment: i want to split single row into multiple rows please guide me

Comment: already some people solved this type of problems, check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Comment: not clear from that solution

Answer (score 0):

My sql Query

```
 $this->db->select('rank')->from('rank_restriction');
            $data = $this->db->get();
            $query = $data->result_array();

              foreach ($query as $result) {
            if (!empty($result['rank'])) {
                $result['rank'] = explode('||', $result['rank']);
            }
return $query
        }
```

Comment: no it return in same row but i want to split row in multiple rows